# Skyrim on the ps3 no mods

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I recently did my started the dawngaurd dlc and I wanted to cure my seeks off werewolf (despite the Vampire Lord removing it) or didn't work so I stated the purify quest for vilkas and it told me my follower left me services I walked out Serena came out with vilkas and he walked back inside I talked to him he said looking for work I said yes had to rescue someone now im art the point were I need to funny thw mouth priest I want to bring Serena but she says I have some one but i don't the people I rescued are home Serena was my only follower and nobody will join me i cane load back and I can't remember witch quests force me a follower and I can't load back to previous save.

And I didn't ask any body to follow me i waited days(enough days to become blood starved) and i reloaded help would be appreciated if nothing works ill do more of the Dragon born questline until that skall lady joins me(hopefully by force).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you complete your "Moth Priest" Quest Serena will start to Follow you again

I was once in the same scenario and just simply did the mission and after that Serena will start taking orders again.

if this doesn't help let me know and i will try to reply quickly

Comment: Ok ill try it and will let u know if it works